# Hangfire: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I'm trying to use [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) in my ASP MVC application, I have configured my application as follows:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseHangfire(config =>
        {
            config.UseSqlServerStorage("myconnstring");
            config.UseServer();
        });
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error every time I run my app:

```
[NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.]    
System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.get_Location() +56       
log4net.Util.SystemInfo.AssemblyLocationInfo(Assembly myAssembly) +88   
log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.GetInfoForAssembly(Assembly assembly, String& repositoryName, Type& repositoryType) +256    
log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.CreateRepository(Assembly repositoryAssembly, Type repositoryType, String repositoryName, Boolean readAssemblyAttributes) +270    
log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.CreateRepository(Assembly repositoryAssembly, Type repositoryType) +58
log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.GetRepository(Assembly repositoryAssembly) +115    
log4net.Core.LoggerManager.GetLogger(Assembly repositoryAssembly, String name) +180    
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly repositoryAssembly, String name) +50    
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(String name) +55
lambda_method(Closure , String ) +39    
Hangfire.Logging.LogProviders.Log4NetLogProvider.GetLogger(String name) +50    
Hangfire.Logging.LogProvider.GetLogger(String name) +103  
Hangfire.Logging.LogProvider.GetLogger(Type type) +53    
Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerObjectsInstaller..cctor() +65
```

Comment: log4net is triying to get the location of the repositoryAssemby. If the assembly is dynamic there is no file, so there is no location in disk. That is why NotSupportedException.

Comment: Is there an InnerException, 'under' the log4net exception?